# CSS font is not displayed in Firefox

Tags: html, css

On my page I have included the font Avantgarde Gothic ITC. The font was initially displayed in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Since last week the font is no longer displayed in Firefox. In Internet Explorer the font is still displayed.

Why is the font no longer displayed in Firefox? How can I fix it?

Many thanks for your help

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "AvantGardeGothicITC W05 Medium";
    src: url("Fonts/5184944/aecfeb5c-7776-4283-977b-12f15fc19819.eot?#iefix");
    src: url("Fonts/5184944/aecfeb5c-7776-4283-977b-12f15fc19819.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
         url("Fonts/5184944/21ab8edd-6587-44cb-b61b-eeb5e3a86beb.woff2") format("woff2"),
         url("Fonts/5184944/cbc28fce-7ac1-4cce-8185-74a371396b03.woff") format("woff"),
         url("Fonts/5184944/e3968950-7cfe-4ba6-bc70-47204c3fb8d0.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: "AvantGardeGothicITC W05 Medium";
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #009B00;
}
```

Comment: did you test with important option font-family: "AvantGardeGothicITC W05 Medium" !important;

Comment: I tested with important option. Unfortunately the font is not displayed.

Comment: Bearing in mind all the answers provided here_ and you saying your code conforms to all of them_ then perhaps it's time to look at the Firefox browser that you're using? Firefox Developer's Edition has a notorious problem with clearing the browser cache which has actually been the subject of questions on SO _ Perhaps your problem is related to this issue?